# Como obtengo un dato con condicion en json?

Tags: php, json

Buenas!,

Hace ya vario tiempo estoy buscando una solución para mi problema, les daré un ejemplo:

Tengo el siguiente archivo JSON:

```
{
"datos": [
        {
            "user_r": "22543341",
            "user_n": "15678798"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "06183254",
            "user_n": "15674578"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "04088869",
            "user_n": "15674567"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "01215181",
            "user_n": "15679876"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "01311283",
            "user_n": "15674557"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "05302433",
            "user_n": "15673465"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "04485424",
            "user_n": "15670756"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "04088872",
            "user_n": "15677653"
        },
        {
            "user_r": "00892195",
            "user_n": "15675623"
        }
    ]
}
```

Y necesito obtener el valor de user_n donde user_r sea el que yo especifique, si no me entendieron, que mejor que hacerlo en SQL: `SELECT user_n WHERE user_r = 22543341`.

Espero su respuesta, gracias! :D

Comment: Hola @Alejandro. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías aclarar en qué formato estás recibiendo/asignando el JSON, y qué intentaste hasta ahora? Este tipo de preguntas suelen considerarse incompletas y sería genial si pudieses [edit] la pregunta aportando más información. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sería usar [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) para convertir a `Json` el `String` dado y luego recorrer con un `for` hasta que el valor de `user_r`  sea el que desee.

```
<?php 

$values = '{
   "datos": [
    {
        "user_r": "22543341",
        "user_n": "15678798"
    },
    {
        "user_r": "06183254",
        "user_n": "15674578"
    }

  ]
 }';
  $json = json_decode($values);
  foreach($json->datos as $item)
  {
    if($item->user_r  == "22543341")
    {
     echo $item->user_n;
    }
 }

?>
```